# $(\lambda I-A)^{-1}C\subset C,\forall \lambda\in\Bbb K:\Re(\lambda)>\|A\|\implies e^{tA}C\subset C,\forall t\in\Bbb R$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

This is the exercise 25 in the book *Analysis II* of Amann and Escher, page 148.

> Let $C$ a closed and convex subset of $E$ and $A\in\mathcal L(E)$. Show that these statements are equivalent:
>
> 1. $e^{tA}C\subset C$ for all $t\in\Bbb R$.
> 2. $(\lambda I-A)^{-1}C\subset C$ for all $\lambda\in\Bbb K$ such that $\Re(\lambda)>\|A\|$.

*(Note: here $E$ is a Banach space and $\Bbb K=\Bbb R\text{ or }\Bbb C$.)*

I know that $$e^{tA}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(I-\frac{t}nA\right)^{-n},\quad (\lambda I-A)^{-1}=\int_0^\infty e^{-s(\lambda I-A)}\mathrm ds$$

What I had tried

$(ii)\implies (i)$ If $n>\|A\|$ then the operator $n I-A$ is invertible. Now observe that

$$n I-A=n\left(I-\frac1{n}A\right)\implies (n I-A)^{-1}=\frac1{n}\left(I-\frac1{n}A\right)^{-1}\tag1$$

Now if I use recursively the last result I get

$$n^{-n}\left(I-\frac1{n}A\right)^{-n}C\subset C$$

for all $n>\|A\|$. But due to the factor $n^{-n}$ I cant show that $e^AC\subset C$. Some help will be appreciated, thank you.

---

W.I.P.: from the comments I assume there is some typo or lack of some important information in the exercise so I will try to add some restrictions on it. By example: it can be seen that assuming $E=\Bbb R$ and $A=I$ and $\lambda,t\in\Bbb R$ (in addition to $\Re(\lambda)>\|A\|$) and some perfect interval the statement holds.

So maybe assuming these conditions for arbitrary real Banach space $E$ the exercise make sense. That is: $\lambda,t\in\Bbb R$ and $C\subset E$ is a closed and convex subset with more than one point in it.

Thus, trying to show $(ii)\implies (i)$ we want to find some "valid" expression in terms of linear functions $(\lambda I-A)^{-1}$ to prove that $(I-\frac{t}nA)^{-1}C\subset C$, what will let me show that $e^{tA}C\subset C$.

Because $C$ is convex then

$$\frac{\sum_{k=0}^n r_k(\lambda_k I-A)^{-k}}{\sum_{k=0}^n r_k}C\subset C$$

for arbitrary $r_k>0$ and $\lambda_k>\|A\|$. Then taking $r_k=\frac1{k!}$ and $\lambda_k=m$, and by the closedness of $C$ we find that

$$e^{-1}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(m I-A)^{-k}}{k!}C=e^{(m I-A)^{-1}-I}C\subset C$$

However from the last expression it is not so clear how I can prove that $e^{tA}C\subset C$.

Comment: What is $\Bbb K$?

Comment: @Robert $\Bbb K=\Bbb R\text{ or }\Bbb C$

Comment: I added a couple of tags to your post.

Comment: Something seems to be missing.Take $A=0$ and $C$ to be a singleton containing a non zero point, then (i) is trivially true. However (ii) implies that $0 \in C$. Where did you get this proposition from?

Comment: @copper.hat:  doesn't (i) imply that $Ax = x$?  That is, isn't $(e^{At}x)' = Ae^{At}x \in C$, whence with $t = 0$ we get $Ax = x$ if $C$ has only one element $x$.  But if $A = 0$ this yields $x = 0$, so it seems consistent with (ii) in this case . . . have ***I*** missed something?

Comment: @copper I had written the entire exercise. There is nothing left. I will edit to add the source.

Comment: @RobertLewis: Hi Bob, if $A=0$ then $e^{At} = I$ for all $t$ so $I C = C$. If $C$ is a non zero singleton then (2) implies that ${1 \over \lambda  } C \subset C$ for all $\lambda$ with positive real part, hence $C$ is star shaped, which is a contradiction. I would suspect that $C$ needs to be affine or possibly a linear subspace.